# BootStrap not rendering on website. Error 404

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap

Doing this in angular. This happens every time. I checked the network in firefox, inspect element, in the console, it shows `bootstrap Error 404`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MeanApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-    alpha.5/css/bootstrap.css">

</head>   
<body>
  <div style="text-align:center">
  <app-root></app-root>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[How my site looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDHA8.png)

[How it is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx69Q.png)

Comment: There is whitespace between 4.0.0 and alpha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a broken URL in your code, remove the whitespace in the middle:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Comment: @LonelyBat I just tested this, my page is loading bootstrap.css. Now what do you mean by not working? Are you still getting 404 on the css or the styles are not working as you want them to?

Comment: actually its working already. i forgot to ng build . Dumbass me

Answer (score 0):

Using Angular 2+ you can include bootstrap using cli

1. Install bootstrap: `npm install --save bootstrap@4.1.3`
2. Add dependency jquery, install it with the command: `npm install --save jquery 1.9.1`
3. Add @import ../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";  to your main    style.scss file.
4. Fix vulnerability : `npm audit fix`

or as told by Aragorn you can directly use CDN